# Spark "reduceByKey" calls reducer more times than expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe of four rows with the same key like this:

```
row_no id  age  time
1      abc  70  1524299530
2      abc  69  1524299528
3      abc  68  1524299526
4      abc  67  1524299524
```

Then I tried to call `reduceByKey` on this dataframe like this:

```
new_rdd = df.rdd \
        .map(lambda row: (row['id'], [row['age'], row['time']])) \
        .reduceByKey(some_reducer)
```

In `some_reducer`, for the purpose of testing I simply return the previous obj. I used `print` to trace the invocation of the reducer and found that spark had invoked the reducer for four times, namely, `(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3) and (1, 3)`. Basically, the reducer was called on row 1 and 3 twice. I was running spark locally with 4 processors. I also tried to run spark with 1 processor on this job and the reducer was called three times as expected on `(1, 2), (3, 4) and (1, 3)`. It must have something to do with how spark partitions the data but it is still hard to make sense of this behavior. Can someone provide explanation for this behavior?

**Update:** I did a more constructive test by sticking an extra integer column on each row and make a reducer to just be `lambda a, b: a + b`. I clearly observed that spark did four additions when run with multi-processor mode in total: `1 + 1`, `1 + 1`, `2 + 2` and `2 + 2`. However, the final result is still 4. In some way, spark discarded the duplicated reducing of `2 + 2`. The question is why there were duplicated reducing in the first place and how spark deals with them?